# Pygame - Python3.x text and sound only work some of the time at a certain part

Tags: python, pygame

This is everything

```
from pygame import *
import random as rand
from colors import *
import os
import time
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)
pygame.init()
fps = 60
window_size = window_width, window_height = 800, 600
font = pygame.font.SysFont( "Power Green, Times New Roman, Arial", 25  )
score = 0

pygame.mixer.music.load('music.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
explode = pygame.mixer.Sound("explode.wav")


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #sprite for player
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("plane.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.setprop()
        self.xspeed = 0




    def setprop( self ):

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.orgin_x = self.rect.centerx
        self.orgin_y = self.rect.centery

    def set_position(self, x, y):
        self.rect.x = x - self.orgin_x
        self.rect.y = y - self.orgin_y

    def update(self):
        self.xspeed = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.xspeed = -9
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.xspeed = 9
        self.rect.x += self.xspeed

        if self.rect.right > window_width:
            self.rect.right = window_width

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
        sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets.add(bullet)

class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image  = pygame.image.load("boulder.png")
        self.rect   = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = rand.randrange(window_width - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = rand.randrange( -100, -40 )
        self.speedy  = rand.randrange(6, 8)
        self.speedx = rand.randrange( -3, 3 )

    def play_sound(self):
        self.sound.play()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.top > window_height + 10 or self.rect.left < -20 or self.rect.right > window_width + 20:
            self.rect.x = rand.randrange(window_width - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = rand.randrange( -100, -40 )
            self.speedy  = rand.randrange(6, 10 )



class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 20))
        self.image.fill(red)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedy = -10

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.bottom > 0:
            self.kill


def health_bars(player_health):
    if player_health > 75:
        player_health_color = green
    elif player_health > 50: 
        player_health_color = yellow
    else:
        player_health_color = red

    pygame.draw.rect(window, player_health_color, (20,20, player_health, 25))

def set_message(text):
    global message, previous_message
    message = font.render( 'HEALTH:' + str(player_health), True, white )
    previous_message = message

def set_score(text):
    global scoremsg
    scoremsg = font.render( 'SCORE:' + str(score), True, white )







sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
sprites.add(player)
for i in range(12):
    m = Mob()
    sprites.add(m)
    mobs.add(m)




player.set_position( window_width/2, window_height/2 +215 )       

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( window_size, pygame.RESIZABLE )
pygame.display.set_caption('Dodge the boulders or shoot them (shooting gets you score)')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
zap = pygame.mixer.Sound("zap.wav")
GAMEOVER = pygame.mixer.Sound("gameover.wav")

player_health = 100

running = True

while ( running ):

    clock.tick( fps )
    set_message( player_health)
    set_score(set_score)

    if (player_health == 0):

        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        #window.blit(gameovertext, (window_width/2, window_height/2))
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(GAMEOVER)



        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
                running = False


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if( event.key == pygame.K_SPACE ):
                player.shoot()








    window.fill(black)
    health_bars(player_health)
    sprites.update()
    #collide group with group
    hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs, bullets, True, True)
    if hits:
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(zap)
        score += 1
    for hit in hits:
        m = Mob()
        sprites.add(m)
        mobs.add(m)


    #collide sprite with group
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs, False)
    if hits:    
        player_health = player_health - 1

    sprites.draw(window)
    window.blit( message, (20, 50) )
    window.blit( scoremsg, (window_width/2 + 320, window_height - 35) )

    if (player_health == 0):

        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        gameoverfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Power Green", 100)

        gameovertext = gameoverfont.render("GAME OVER", True, white )
        window.blit(gameovertext, (window_width / 2 - 160, window_height / 2 -75))
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(GAMEOVER)
    pygame.display.update()


pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
```

and this is the part I'm having issues with:

if (player_health == 0):

```
pygame.mixer.music.stop()
gameoverfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Power Green", 100)

gameovertext = gameoverfont.render("GAME OVER", True, white )
window.blit(gameovertext, (window_width / 2 - 160, window_height / 2 -75))
pygame.mixer.Sound.play(GAMEOVER)
pygame.display.update()
```

What's weird is that the text appears some of the time, and it happens for varying amounts of time.  I got one of the longer times the GAMEOVER text appears on recording at this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xf8aKx4SOTc

I'd appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here, I'm quite new to pygame itself.
Edit: Alright youtube appears to be down.  Basically what it was, was GAME OVER displaying for about 1.5 seconds before dissapeaing, and then the gameover voice audio would play twice. (not sure why twice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have two `if (player_health == 0):` , try to join the needed lines in only one, this should resolve the sound-played-twice issue.

Also, you are using the same name `hits` to detect collision with bullets **and** mobs, it would be more readable and easier to use different names, and by doing this you avoid confusion with the score.

When it's GAME OVER, the loop is still running, and nothing prevent the score to increase or decrease. 
With the `if hits:` for mobs, you should add another condition in the test, like :

```
if hits and player_health > 0: 
    player_health = player_health - 1
```

Otherwise you should change the health test to

```
if (player_health <= 0):
```

I hope this can fix the text displayed issue.